# Undefined index Laravel controller function "store"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Fellow Coders,

I am currently developing an hour registration system for the company i'm an intern at. The problem i have right now though, is that when I add a new row to the table form in which colleagues can add their task(s) and hours with ajax. I get an undefined index error even though the variable is set (Or so I would like to believe).

Here is my Ajax/javascript code to append a new row and to use the ajax function

Ajax:
      addRows++;

```
  $(".btn-save").click(function(){

    rowId = $(this).attr('rel');

    var url = '/hoursregistrations/create';
    var data = {
        user_id: {{  $user_id->id }},
        project_id: $("tr#addRow-"+rowId + " .project_id").val(),
        note: $("tr#addRow-"+rowId + "  .note").val(),
        hours: $("tr#addRow-"+rowId + " .hours").val(),
        date: $("tr#addRow-"+rowId +  " .date").val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
        headers:{ 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        type: 'post',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("table tbody").append(markup);
        //redirect
        if(type=="exit")
            window.location = "create.blade.php";
    }
});
});
```

});

});

Append:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
addRows = 0;
$("#addField").click(function (){
  var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
  var project_id = $('#project_id').val();
  var note = $('#note').val();
  var date = $('#date').val();
  var hours = $('#hours').val();
  var markup = "<tr id='addRow-"+(addRows)+"'><td hidden>{{  $user_id->first_name }}</td></td>"
  + user_id + 
  " <td> <select class='project_id' value=''><option>{!! \App\Project::getCompanyName($hoursregistration->project_id) !!} - {!! \App\Subproject::getTaskTitle($hoursregistration->subproject_id)!!}</option></td>"
  + project_id +
  "<td><input type='text' value='{{ $hoursregistration->note }}' name='note' class='note'></td></td>"
  + note +   
  "<td><input type='date' class='date' value='{!! \App\Helpers::dateFormat($hoursregistration->date) !!}'></td>"
  + date +
  "<td><input type='hours' class='hours' value='{{ $hoursregistration->hours }}'></td></td>"
  + hours +
  "<td><button id='btn-save' name='btn-save' class='btn btn-default btn-xd btn-save save-hoursregistration' value='' rel='addRow-"+addRows+"'>Save</button>"
  $("table tbody").append(markup);
```

The identation etc. Is good, I'm just unable to post code here haha..

```
Store function in the Controller

public function store(Request $request)
{
    //$hoursregistration= new Hoursregistration($request->except(''));


    $input = Input::all();

    $hoursregistration = new Hoursregistration();
    $hoursregistration->user_id = Sentinel::getUser()->id;
    $hoursregistration->project_id = $input['project_id'];
    $hoursregistration->subproject_id = $input['subproject_id'];
    $hoursregistration->date = $input['date'];
    $hoursregistration->note = $input['note'];
    $hoursregistration->hours = $input['hours'];
           //   dd($hoursregistration); 
    $hoursregistration->save();
    return redirect('hoursregistrations')->with('success', Lang::get('message.success.create'));
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of my Undefined Index "project_id" error?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Routes of the app:

```
            Route::group(array('prefix' => 'hoursregistrations'), function () {
            Route::get('/', array('as' => 'hoursregistrations.index', 'uses' => 'HoursregistrationsController@index', function(){
                $projects = Project::all();
                return View::make('index')->with('hoursregistrations', $hoursregistrations);
            }));



            Route::get('data', ['as' => 'hoursregistrations.data', 'uses' => 'HoursregistrationsController@data']);

            Route::get('/create', array('as' => 'hoursregistrations.create', 'uses' => 'HoursregistrationsController@create'));
            Route::post('/create', 'HoursregistrationsController@store');
            Route::get('/show/{id}', array('as' => 'hoursregistrations.show', 'uses' => 'HoursregistrationsController@show'));
            Route::get('/edit/{id}', array('as' => 'hoursregistrations.edit', 'uses' => 'HoursregistrationsController@edit'));

            Route::post('/edit/{id}/update', array('as' => 'hoursregistrations.update', 'uses' => 'HoursregistrationsController@update'));
            Route::get('/{id}/delete', array('as' => 'hoursregistrations.delete', 'uses' => 'HoursregistrationsController@getDelete'));
            Route::get('/{id}/confirm-delete', array('as' => 'hoursregistrations.confirm-delete', 'uses' => 'HoursregistrationsController@getModalDelete'));
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body table-responsive">
            <!-- Tabel om de data te weergeven -->
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="filters"> 
                       <th>Titel Project</th>
                       <th>Notitie</th>
                       <th>Datum</th>
                       <th>Uren</th>
                       <th>Actions</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody id="content">
                @foreach ($hoursregistrations as $hoursregistration)
                <tr>
                   <td hidden>{{  $user_id->first_name }}</td>
                   <td >{!! App\Project::getCompanyName($hoursregistration->project_id) !!} - {!! \App\Subproject::getTaskTitle($hoursregistration->subproject_id)!!}</td>      
                   <td>{!! $hoursregistration->note !!}</td>    
                   <td>{!! \App\Helpers::dateFormat($hoursregistration->date) !!}</td>
                   <td>{!! $hoursregistration->hours !!}</td>
                   <td>
                    <button id="btn-edit" name="btn-edit" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-detail open-modal" value="{{$hoursregistration->id}}">Edit</button>
                    <button id="btn-delete" name="btn-delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete delete-hoursregistration" value="{{ $hoursregistration->id }}">Delete</button>
                    <button id="btn-save" name="btn-save" class="btn btn-default btn-xd btn-save save-hoursregistration" value="">Save</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- End: tabel die data weergeeft -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please can you post your routes?

Comment: It might be a stupid comment here, but I have done nothing at my routes... Wow. Would you be able to help me create a route that passes the values?

Comment: Edtied the question, and added the routes file

Comment: did you check your `rowId` has correct value??

Comment: I did check the appended rows for values in the console log. Every single piece of value is present IT SAYS. But when I click the save button to proccess the AJAX request. IT only shows the user id which is correct, but it ignores the rest of the values. And gives me an undefined index error

Comment: Check your request via devtools. I guess there are no variables sent

Comment: I just checked the rowId. And yes it works as it should (making a new Id for a new row)

Comment: I came as far as that @AlexSlipknot . If I use the console log to check if the values of the appended row is filled in. It just shows the values, so that's good in a sense. The only thing is which I just found out. That the values do not get sent. Hence why it gives me an error because it's null. I got no clue why it does this, that's why i'm asking for help c:

Comment: so, are they present in the request?

Comment: In my console log I can succesfully print out the values from the input fields yes. But for some reason those values do not correspond with the given variables used to pass in ajax

Comment: I mean sure, the user Id is easily found if the person is logged in. But then again, I have no clue why I cannot use the $project_id. Maybe i'm just dumb or something I don't know.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe you didn't understand what's exactly request should be. Look at the request parameters that must be sent like that: http://i.imgur.com/wTgcKJf.jpg (https://jsfiddle.net/ucrt2x13/)

Comment: That's exactly how it should be sent through. But in my case, I only receive the user_id of the logged in account i'm testing on. The other values refuse getting past

Comment: On the other hand, I really appreciate the work you are doing to try to help me in this situation..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142580/discussion-between-alex-slipknot-and-kayelder).

Comment: Post HTML of the view

Comment: If you add `dd($input)` you'll see what values are being collected by `Input::all()`. You also need to [read the documentation for HTTP requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#accessing-the-request). You should be using `$request->all()` instead of `Input::all()`.

Comment: Why don't you use `$request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys in your data object you are posting with AJAX must have quotations if you are to call them as you do.

```
var data = {
    'user_id': {{  $user_id->id }},
    'project_id': $("tr#addRow-"+rowId + " .project_id").val(),
    'note': $("tr#addRow-"+rowId + "  .note").val(),
    'hours': $("tr#addRow-"+rowId + " .hours").val(),
    'date': $("tr#addRow-"+rowId +  " .date").val(),
};
```

Alternatively you must convert your data to a JSON string as a part of the request, using [JSON.stringify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/json-stringify-function-javascript)

```
$.ajax({
    headers:{ 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    type: 'post',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    //redirect
    if(type=="exit")
        window.location = "create.blade.php";
}
```

Comment: As this does not work, I have made it work a bit bythe help of @alexSlipKnot. The problem turned out to be in ("tr#addRow-"+rowId + " .project_id").val(). Which refused to take values

Comment: i'll just accept this answer to make you happy aswell, since you put effort in answering